# Installation tensorflow with conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, gpu, conda

When we pip install all packages of python.

Why we cannot install with conda directly?

just like `conda install tensorlfow-gpu==1.2.1` or `conda install tensorflow==1.2.1`.

when i am using `conda install tensorflow-gpu` I get these type of error.

> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect
>   to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

Answer (score 0):

From the error one can understand that you need to install `OpenSSL` for Python.

For that do

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev
```

and then

```
conda install -c anaconda openssl
```

If you still have the problem (if execstack flag is the issue):

```
execstack -c path_to_anaconda/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: i am solve my error when i am used == cannot install.

Comment: conda install tensorlfow-gpu=1.2.1 . correct installation cmd.